# 2 queries during pagination in ORM

Tags: hibernate, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I have started to dive into ORMs and suddenly a question popped into my head:
Does ORMs like Hibernate and SqlAlchemy fire 2 queries when we use their pagination functionality?

- If no, then how do they show the total result set count in spite of setting pageNo and pageSize?
- If yes, is it efficient? Running an extra query against all the records in the table to get the actual count and then running a second query with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

The pagination object in `flask-sqlalchemy` provides properties like `obj.total`, `obj.has_next`, `obj.page`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy works as you'd expect, with two queries-- there's no other way to do it really.

For instance, with a simple `Post` model you get two queries (I've set `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO` to `True` in the config to get these statement's echoed)

```
>>> p = Post.query.paginate(per_page=20, page=5)
2021-05-05 14:51:28,647 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT post.id AS post_id, post.user_id AS post_user_id, post.title AS post_title, post.content AS post_content, post.dttm AS post_dttm 
FROM post
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
2021-05-05 14:51:28,647 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00026s] (20, 80)
2021-05-05 14:51:28,652 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT count(*) AS count_1 
FROM (SELECT post.id AS post_id, post.user_id AS post_user_id, post.title AS post_title, post.content AS post_content, post.dttm AS post_dttm 
FROM post) AS anon_1
2021-05-05 14:51:28,652 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00015s] ()
```

As you can see-- the offset actually fires first, it's not doing logic to limit you to the actual returned rows (you'll just get nothing returned) on the statement level.

Is it efficient to do that? Well-- it's as efficient as it can be given the problem.  I believe there's a recentish commit to Flask-SQLAlchemy, so will be in an upcoming release where you'll be able to optionally disable that `count(*)` second query, but then obviously you can't know how many total pages you have, if that's something you need for your user-interface, so it's give and take.

Your database will do what it can to improve that efficiency, maybe it caches the results if it's a common query, maybe it notices it's only hitting indexed columns and skips a full table-scan.  For example if I rerun that same command with SQLite I get:

```
>>> p = Post.query.paginate(per_page=20, page=5)
2021-05-05 15:02:21,403 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT post.id AS post_id, post.user_id AS post_user_id, post.title AS post_title, post.content AS post_content, post.dttm AS post_dttm 
FROM post
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
2021-05-05 15:02:21,403 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 61.8s ago] (20, 80)
2021-05-05 15:02:21,404 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT count(*) AS count_1 
FROM (SELECT post.id AS post_id, post.user_id AS post_user_id, post.title AS post_title, post.content AS post_content, post.dttm AS post_dttm 
FROM post) AS anon_1
2021-05-05 15:02:21,404 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 61.8s ago] ()
```

Note how it's cached the result from earlier and therefore returns instantly. So, while not a pleasing answer-- it's as efficient as it can generically be.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's not necessary to know how many items there are exactly, but it's enough to just know there are further elements. Spring Data calls this `Slice` rather than `Page`. Essentially, if the page size is N it will fetch N + 1 rows to be able to tell you that there are more elements to fetch. This works best with keyset pagination. You can inline the count query into your main query as select item though and this is what [Blaze-Persistence Pagination](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/#pagination) (works on top of JPA/Hibernate) does by default. All modern databases should be able to figure out that the count query is not correlated and thus only execute it once instead of for every row.

One optimization that ORMs usually don't do is join pruning for the count query. Blaze-Persistence will happily prune all joins and other clauses that are unnecessary though and improve the performance quite a bit due to that. Another way to improve the counting is to avoid counting all elements and instead only count up to a certain bound. Usually, end users don't care if you found 101 results or 1000 results, so why count them all? Blaze-Persistence can easily generate such a bounded count query: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/#bounded-counting